# Substract two alias column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, alias

I passed two query into `inn` and `out` alias column and I want to do this 
`res=(inn-out)` but it gives me an error

```
Invalid column name 'inn'.
Invalid column name 'out'.
?
```

```
select productname
,inn=isnull((select sum(orderqty) 
               from purchasing.purchaseinvoicedetail 
              where productfk=Production.product.productid ),0)
,outt=isnull((select sum(orderqty) 
                from sales.salesinvoicedetail 
               where productfk=Production.product.productid  ),0) 
,res=(inn-outt)
from production.product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this inn and outt can be referenced only outside

```
    Select a.*,inn-outt As [DiffValue] from
    (
    select productname,inn=isnull((select sum(orderqty) from purchasing.purchaseinvoicedetail where productfk=Production.product.productid ),0),
        outt=isnull((select sum(orderqty) from sales.salesinvoicedetail where productfk=Production.product.productid  ),0) 
        from production.product

        ) As a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT t.*, t.Inn - t.outt AS Res
FROM
(
select productname
,inn=isnull((select sum(orderqty) 
               from purchasing.purchaseinvoicedetail 
              where productfk=Production.product.productid ),0)
,outt=isnull((select sum(orderqty) 
                from sales.salesinvoicedetail 
               where productfk=Production.product.productid  ),0) 
from production.product
) t
```